# Вывести в одном цикле разные товары по условию

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь вы вевести товары в одном цикле по условию, в базе есть поле у каждого товара str1,  я хочу чтобы товары с str1 == 0 выводились в одном блоке,а товары с str1 == 1 выводились в другом, но почему-то у меня дублируется заголовок из 1 блока  - Ресторан №1 :

```
 <?php foreach ($content->items as $item): ?>

      <?php if($item['str1'] == 0): ?>

        <h2>Ресторан №1</h2> 
        <tr class="odd views-row-first">
            <td class="views-field views-field-nothing">
          <img src="<?= $item['content']['image'] ?>" width="120" height="80">
                                                        <br>
    </td><td><?= $item['content']['name'] ?></td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price views-align-left price">
    <?= $item['price']/* - ceil(($item['price'] * 7) / 100)*/ ?> руб.          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-edit-quantity">
        <?= $item['count'] ?>
</td>

    <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-left price">
  <span class=""><?= $item['price'] *  $item['count'] /*- ceil((($item['price'] *  $item['count']) * 7) / 100)*/ ?></span>           </td>
   <td class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash cart-delete" data-cart="<?= $item['id'] ?>" title="Удалить"></span></td>
    <td>
 </td>
</tr>

   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php if($item['str1'] == 1): ?>

    <h2>Ресторан №2</h2> 
  <tr class="odd views-row-first">
  <td class="views-field views-field-nothing">
   <img src="<?= $item['content']['image'] ?>" width="120" height="80">
    <br>
  </td><td><?= $item['content']['name'] ?></td>
   <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price views-align-left price">
  <?= $item['price']/* - ceil(($item['price'] * 7) / 100)*/ ?> руб.          </td>
  <td class="views-field views-field-edit-quantity">
   <?= $item['count'] ?>
 </td>

    <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-left price">
   <span class=""><?= $item['price'] *  $item['count'] /*- ceil((($item['price'] *  $item['count']) * 7) / 100)*/ ?></span>           </td>
<td class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash cart-delete" data-cart="<?= $item['id'] ?>" title="Удалить"></span></td>
  <td>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>

    <?php endif; ?>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Если у вас больше одного товара с  `str1 == 0`, то и выводов `Ресторан №1` будет больше одного

Comment: ок,  а как мне сделать чтобы товары в разных блоках выводились, в зависимости от поля str1?

Comment: Создать новий массив с груперовкой по полю `str1`, как описано в ответе ниже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать массив в котором ключ будет обозначать "str1", получится что вы сгруппируете все элементы по данному параметру.

```
array[
  "str1" => [
    item1,
    item2
  ],
  "str2" => [
    item3,
    item4
  ]
]
```

После в шаблоне уже двойным циклов выводите каждый str1 в своем блоке

```
//контроллер
$array = array();
foreach ($content->items as $key => $item){
    $array[$item['str1']][$key] = $item;
}

// view
<?php foreach ($array as $keys):?>
    <div style="background: red; padding: 15px;">
        <?php foreach ($keys as $item): ?>
            <div><?=$item['content']['name']?></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

примерно как то так

```
array[
  "str1" => [
    "title" => "Заголовок 1",
    "values" => [
       item1,
       item2
    ]
  "str2" => [
    "title" => "Заголовок 2",
    "values" => [
       item3,
       item4
    ]
]
```

Comment: мне это в контроллере прописать? и что означает item1, item2...?

Comment: @sergey-dev дополнил ответ, примерно так это будет выгладить.

Comment: все работает, спасибо

Comment: а как мне прописать заголовки, чтобы они не дублировались, а были у каждого блока разные?

Comment: @sergey-dev не понял вопроса, какие заголовки?

Comment: ну например, чтобы в первом блоке выводился один заголовок, а во втором блоке выводился другой

Comment: @sergey-dev дополнил ответ

Comment: да, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @sergey-dev не за что